# Express: next is not called properly inside a catch after await

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, es6-promise

I have a very simple route

```js
router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const allEmployees = await employees.find({});
    res.json(allEmployees);
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});
```

It works ok. But after I refactored it with `catch`. it stopped working and threw `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:`

```js
router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  const allEmployees = await employees.find({}).catch(next)
  res.json(allEmployees);
});
```

It seems like the `next` is not called correctly in the second version. But Both should be equivalent in JavaScript. not sure why the second one is broken in Express.

Comment: When you use `await` errors will be thrown instead of caught by `.catch`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Both should be equivalent in JavaScript

No, they are not.

[Promise.prototype.catch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) returns a new promise that resolves with the return value of the callback. Since `next()` returns `void`, this code...

> ```js
> employees.find({}).catch(next)
> ```

returns a **successful** promise, resolving with `undefined`. `next()` will be called with the failure but there's nothing stopping the rest of your code from calling `res.json(undefined)`.

If you want to use the `Promise` prototype methods, the equivalent would be

```js
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  employees.find({}).then(res.json).catch(next);
});
```

If you wanted to keep using `async` / `await` and have the eventual promise fail, you'd need something like this

```js
router.get("/", async (req, res, next) => {
  const allEmployees = await employees
    .find({})
    .catch((err) => Promise.reject(next())); // rejected result
  res.json(allEmployees);
});
```

Comment: I know how `catch` works in JS. for this `.catch(next);`, it is equivalent of `.catch(e => next(e));` my understand is that once `next` gets called, it is effectively a return statement so `res.json(undefined)` won't be reached.

Comment: @Joji no. Because your `.catch()` returns a successful promise, the rest of your code continues as if everything is ok

Comment: yea I know it returns a successful promise. but `next` is indeed *called* inside of it with the `error` passed to it. so it should behave like a return statement at that point isn't it?

Comment: @Joji no, `next()` just passes the arg to the general error handler but it does not stop anything else from happening.

Comment: got it... so the recommended approach is to just use `try catch` with `await`?

Comment: @Joji that's correct. Express v5 has (will have) better error handling for async handlers. See https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html#catching-errors